# How to discard settings from .vimrc

Tags: vim, neovim

When I `:so some/file`, the settings get added *on top* of my current settings. How do I clear all my settigs (**all** `set`s, and all `*noremap`s) before i source another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you're looking for is in `:h set` and `:h mapclear`.

In particular, you might try `:set all&`, which sets all options (except for a few which are described in the helpfile) to their defaults, and `:mapclear`, which removes all maps. It is likely that you will afterwards want so source your $VIMRC again.

Comment: This with `:mapclear` did the trick. You might want to add it to your answer, for other people to see.

Comment: @Markonius Thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Start `vim` without `.vimrc` at all: [`vim -u NONE`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-u)